# TypeError: OO.ui.MessageDialog is not a constructor when using OOUI/Windows/Message Dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, oojs-ui

I am trying to use OOUI/Windows/Message Dialogs to prompt a user warning. I used code snippet from https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OOUI/Windows/Message_Dialogs to open a Dialogbox.

But when I use `var messageDialog = new OO.ui.MessageDialog();` **this error occurs**- `TypeError: OO.ui.MessageDialog is not a constructor`.

**What might be the problem?**

The code is as following:

```
( function ( $ ) {
    $( '#movepage' ).on( 'submit', function(event){
        var messageDialog = new OO.ui.MessageDialog();

        var windowManager = new OO.ui.WindowManager();
        $( 'body' ).append( windowManager.$element );

        windowManager.addWindows( [ messageDialog ] );

        windowManager.openWindow( messageDialog, {
            title: 'Storage limit reached',
            message: 'You are out of disk space',
            actions: [
                { label: 'Cancel', action: 'cancel' },
                { label: 'Move page', action: 'proceed' }
            ]
        });
    });
}( jQuery ) );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it figured out.

You have to add dependencies `'oojs-ui-core'`, `'oojs-ui-windows'` in `Resources.php`.

eg:

If you are adding the message dialog to the `mediawiki.special.movePage.js`

```
'mediawiki.special.movePage' => [
    'scripts' => 'resources/src/mediawiki.special/mediawiki.special.movePage.js',
    'dependencies' => [
        'jquery.byteLimit',
        'mediawiki.widgets',
        'oojs-ui-core',
        'oojs-ui-windows'
    ],
],
```